# Django cannot makemigrations for a nested app

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-apps

I am trying to create a nested app in my django project, but `makemigrations` is not detecting it. I have the following directory structure:

```
myproject/
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── myproject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── parentapp
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── childapp
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

And here is some relevant code:

**myproject/myproject/settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'parentapp',
    'parentapp.childapp',
]
```

**myproject/parentapp/childapp/__init__.py:**

```
default_app_config = "parentapp.childapp.apps.ChildAppConfig"
```

**myproject/parentapp/childapp/apps.py:**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ChildAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'parentapp.childapp'
```

**myproject/parentapp/childapp/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class Child(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        app_label = "parentapp.childapp"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I see the following behavior when trying to make migrations:

```
$ myproject/manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

$ myproject/manage.py makemigrations childapp
No changes detected in app 'childapp'

$ myproject/manage.py makemigrations parentapp.childapp
'parentapp.childapp' is not a valid app label.  Did you mean 'childapp'?
```

What am I doing wrong?  I see loads of other reusable apps that have nested apps (django-allauth, for example).

Comment: Do you have a `migrations` directory with an `__init__.py` file?

Comment: @gpichot Yes, I do.  Both in "parentapp" and "childapp".

Comment: Can you do a `tree myproject` then and update your question with the output? Did you created the childapp using `startapp` or manually?

Comment: I've added the `tree` output.  And I created childapp using `startapp`.

Comment: Did you tried removing your `app_label` from the `Child` model?

Comment: @gpichot - That's fixed it!  Thanks! If you make this an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: I don't have any app_label in the models, but still failing with same error. Any fix for this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `app_label` from `Child.Meta` or to change it to a compatible app name (no ".", lowercase and underscore).